# Displaying Sub Totals based on Dates in DataRow of DataTable using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve the DataTable like below that displays sub totals after each unique dates having array of objects

Below is the code which I used to sort the array based on unique dates

```
    class _DateWiseReportState extends State<DateWiseReport> {
  List<Map> _reports = [
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '2S',
      'coupon_value': 5,
      'quantity': 3,
      'amount': 15,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '4S',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 2,
      'amount': 20,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '3W',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 2,
      'amount': 20,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '02.07.23',
      'engine_type': '2S',
      'coupon_value': 5,
      'quantity': 2,
      'amount': 10,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '02.07.23',
      'engine_type': '4S',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 3,
      'amount': 30,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '3W',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 3,
      'amount': 30,
    }
  ];

  for (var reportData in _reports) {
       int quantity = reportData['quantity'];
       int amount = reportData['amount'];
       int couponValue = reportData['coupon_value'];

       totalQuantity += quantity.toInt();
       totalAmount += amount.toInt();
       totalCouponValue += couponValue.toInt();
  }

  _reports.sort((a, b) {
      return a['scan_date'].compareTo(b['scan_date']!);
  });

List<DataColumn> _createColumns() {
    return [
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
              child: Text(
        'Scan Date',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text(
        'E-Type',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      )),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
              child: Text(
        'Value',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
              child: Text(
        'QTY',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ))),
      DataColumn(
        label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
          'Amount(Rs)',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        )),
        onSort: (columnIndex, _) {
          setState(() {
            _currentSortColumn = columnIndex;
            if (_isSortAsc) {
              _reports.sort((a, b) => b['amount'].compareTo(a['amount']));
            } else {
              _reports.sort((a, b) => a['amount'].compareTo(b['amount']));
            }
            _isSortAsc = !_isSortAsc;
          });
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<DataRow> _createRows() {
    return _reports
        .map((report) => DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                    report['scan_date'].toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ), onTap: () {
                print("Clicked row at scan_date");
              }),
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                    report['engine_type'].toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ), onTap: () {
                print("Clicked row at engine_type");
              }),
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                    report['coupon_value'].toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ), onTap: () {
                print("Clicked row at coupon_value");
              }),
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                    report['quantity'].toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ), onTap: () {
                print("Clicked row at quantity");
              }),
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                    report['amount'].toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ), onTap: () {
                print("Clicked row at amount");
              })
            ]))
        .toList();
  }
```

[image: Present Output]

[image: Required Output]

Can anyone suggest how we can achieve the sub totals based on after unique dates.

Comment: try `fold()` method : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include sample data so that we can work with?

Comment: @MendelG I have added sample data. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Result

[image]

##### Explanation

I've refactored your code and created a `_createRows` function where the main logic is:

```dart
   List<DataRow> _createRows() {
    List<DataRow> rows = [];
    int currentSubtotalAmount = 0;

    // Flag for first iteration otherwise it will add subtotal row at the beginning
    bool isFirstIteration = true;

    _reports.sort((a, b) {
      final aDate = a['scan_date'] as String;
      final bDate = b['scan_date'] as String;
      return aDate.compareTo(bDate);
    });

    for (var report in _reports) {
      final reportDate = report['scan_date'] as String;

      if (reportDate != currentDate) {
        // Add a subtotal row for the previous date group
        if (currentDate.isNotEmpty && currentSubtotalAmount > 0) {
          rows.add(_createSubtotalRow(currentSubtotalAmount));
          currentSubtotalAmount = 0;
        }

        currentDate = reportDate;

        // Only add date row if it's not the first iteration
        if (!isFirstIteration) {
          rows.add(_createDateRow(currentDate));
        }
      }

      rows.add(_createReportRow(report));

      currentSubtotalAmount += report['amount'] as int;

      // After first iteration, set the flag to false
      if (isFirstIteration) {
        isFirstIteration = false;
      }
    }

    // Add a final subtotal row
    rows.add(_createSubtotalRow(currentSubtotalAmount));

    return rows;
  }
```

The loop iterates through each report in the `_reports` list:

If the current report's `'scan_date'` is different from the `currentDate`, it means a *new* date group has started. And in that case:

- If currentDate is not empty (Meaning, not the first date
  encountered), it adds a subtotal row for the previous date
  group using `_createSubtotalRow(currentSubtotalAmount)`.
- It resets currentSubtotalAmount to 0 because a new date group has started

##### Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(ExampleWidget());
}

class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DateWiseReport(),
    );
  }
}

class DateWiseReport extends StatefulWidget {
  const DateWiseReport({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DateWiseReport> createState() => _DateWiseReportState();
}

class _DateWiseReportState extends State<DateWiseReport> {
  final _reports = [
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '2S',
      'coupon_value': 5,
      'quantity': 3,
      'amount': 15,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '4S',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 2,
      'amount': 20,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '3W',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 2,
      'amount': 20,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '02.07.23',
      'engine_type': '2S',
      'coupon_value': 5,
      'quantity': 2,
      'amount': 10,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '02.07.23',
      'engine_type': '4S',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 3,
      'amount': 30,
    },
    {
      'scan_date': '01.07.23',
      'engine_type': '3W',
      'coupon_value': 10,
      'quantity': 3,
      'amount': 30,
    }
  ];

  
  late String currentDate = _reports[0]['scan_date'] as String;

  void _sortReportsByAmount() {
    _reports.sort((a, b) {
      final aAmount = a['amount'] as int;
      final bAmount = b['amount'] as int;
      return aAmount.compareTo(bAmount);
    });
  }

  List<DataColumn> _createColumns() {
    return [
      DataColumn(label: Text('Scan Date', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      DataColumn(label: Text('E-Type', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Value', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      DataColumn(label: Text('QTY', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('Amount(Rs)', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        onSort: (columnIndex, _) {
          setState(() {
            _sortReportsByAmount();
          });
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<DataRow> _createRows() {
    List<DataRow> rows = [];
    int currentSubtotalAmount = 0;

    // Flag for first iteration otherwise it will add subtotal row at the beginning
    bool isFirstIteration = true;

    _reports.sort((a, b) {
      final aDate = a['scan_date'] as String;
      final bDate = b['scan_date'] as String;
      return aDate.compareTo(bDate);
    });

    for (var report in _reports) {
      final reportDate = report['scan_date'] as String;

      if (reportDate != currentDate) {
        // Add a subtotal row for the previous date group
        if (currentDate.isNotEmpty && currentSubtotalAmount > 0) {
          rows.add(_createSubtotalRow(currentSubtotalAmount));
          currentSubtotalAmount = 0;
        }

        currentDate = reportDate;

        // Only add date row if it's not the first iteration
        if (!isFirstIteration) {
          rows.add(_createDateRow(currentDate));
        }
      }

      rows.add(_createReportRow(report));

      currentSubtotalAmount += report['amount'] as int;

      // After first iteration, set the flag to false
      if (isFirstIteration) {
        isFirstIteration = false;
      }
    }

    // Add a final subtotal row
    rows.add(_createSubtotalRow(currentSubtotalAmount));

    return rows;
  }

  DataRow _createDateRow(String date) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(date, textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      DataCell(Text(''), // Empty cell for E-Type
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked date cell");
      }),
      DataCell(Text(''), // Empty cell for Value
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked date cell");
      }),
      DataCell(Text(''), // Empty cell for QTY
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked date cell");
      }),
      DataCell(Text(''), // Empty cell for Amount
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked date cell");
      }),
    ]);
  }

  DataRow _createReportRow(Map<String, dynamic> report) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(
          Text(report['scan_date'].toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked row at scan_date");
      }),
      DataCell(
          Text(report['engine_type'].toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked row at engine_type");
      }),
      DataCell(
          Text(report['coupon_value'].toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked row at coupon_value");
      }),
      DataCell(Text(report['quantity'].toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked row at quantity");
      }),
      DataCell(Text(report['amount'].toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          onTap: () {
        print("Clicked row at amount");
      }),
    ]);
  }

  DataRow _createSubtotalRow(int subtotalAmount) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: [
        DataCell(Text(
          'Subtotal',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )),
        DataCell(Text(''), // Empty cell for E-Type
            onTap: () {
          print("Clicked subtotal cell");
        }),
        DataCell(Text(''), // Empty cell for Value
            onTap: () {
          print("Clicked subtotal cell");
        }),
        DataCell(Text(''), // Empty cell for QTY
            onTap: () {
          print("Clicked subtotal cell");
        }),
        DataCell(
            Text(subtotalAmount.toString(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onTap: () {
          print("Clicked subtotal cell");
        }),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Date Wise Report'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: _createColumns(),
          rows: _createRows(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```